# Resolving/publishing C/C++ dependencies with Gradle and Artifactory?

Tags: c++, gradle, dependency-management, artifactory

I want to ease adoption of dependency management in my organization, and it does not seem to be as easy of a task with C/C++ as it is with Java.

I want to use an internal Artifactory repository (Maven, Ivy, Gradle or whatever is suitable) to essentially be able to download and publish external libraries which have been precompiled to then statically link them (catch: we are using a custom compiler for an embedded platform)

I have read what it seems to be the basic guide from Gradle's website, however there is no mention of external repositories:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html
http://gradle.monochromeroad.com/docs/userguide/nativeBinaries.html

These two threads seem to touch on the subject, but I'm confused as to where the linking is happening and in what order:

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/external-dependencies-in-cpp-projects/7135
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/right-way-to-copy-contents-from-dependency-archives/7449

So far I cannot wrap my mind around some of the closures/syntax and correct usage of stuff like "configurations", "dependencies", "repositories" because they seem to be used in different ways.

With all that said, **what would be a minimal example to get the following done?**:

- Go to Artifactory
- Fetch a dependency (let's assume it is a .a or .o file)
- Put that individual dependency in a specific location within the project
- Build (specifying the linking order and compiler)

Comment: the two discuss.gradle links you posted have complete examples of how you can get this, what additional information are you looking for?

Comment: The only Artifactory Repository that is suitable for your use case is Generic, Maven \ Gradle etc. impose restrictions on paths and what metadata is used or generated for artifacts.

Comment: I am looking for same. Docs seem scant. Here are some samples that I have not tried yet: https://github.com/gradle/native-samples/blob/master/cpp